# Convert videos to webm via ffmpeg faster

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following params via ffmpeg to convert videos to webm format:

```
-c:v libvpx -qmin 0 -qmax 50 -crf 4 -b:v 2M -c:a libvorbis -q:a 10
```

However it takes lot of time (more than 5 minutes) just to convert 5 MB video. Can I write some other params to make the conversion fast?

Answer (score 32):

`ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libvpx -cpu-used -5 -deadline realtime out.webm`

The `-cpu-used` and `-deadline` options control speed/quality for libvpx codec. See `ffmpeg -h full` for details in the `libvpx-vp8 encoder AVOptions` section.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely speeds it up a ton. We're talking an hour for a 5 minute video shot on my phone to 10 minutes for the same video.

Comment: How is this the only post I've found that mentions `deadline` re speed? We got a 4-5x speed increase using `-deadline realtime`.