# Quickest way to convert HD videos to webm

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gentoo

I'm currently using the following command to convert .mp4 videos into .webm.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vpre libvpx-720p -b 3900k -an -f webm -y output.webm
```

I appreciate that I'm converting in HD format, but the conversion takes a very long time. Is there anything I can do to speed it up? I'm running it directly on my web server and trying to tie it in with Node.js as part as a content management system

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't worry about this now, after I posted it a related question appeared on the right hand side with exactly what I was looking for. I added -cpu-used and -deadline and it's much quicker now

Comment: You should provide a link to the post so others can benefit from it. Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: VPx Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide).

Comment: Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665982/convert-videos-to-webm-via-ffmpeg-faster?rq=1