# How does big companies transcode/encode videos so fast?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, transcoding, handbrake

For example how does Facebook, YouTube, Reddit and many countless sites encode videos so fast? Do they all have in-house solutions? Tools like FFMPEG and Handbrake are alot slower to how they process files.

I had a hard time deciding if this should be posted on the softwareengineering stackexchange then decided stackoverflow seemed more fit for the question.

Comment: The basic flow is to segment the input, encode segments in parallel, then stitch the results.

Comment: Hi @Gyan! Thanks for your reply, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673805/13089988) on a different question and using those arguments dropped conversion time from almost 2 minutes to 11 seconds, are any of these arguments considered dangerous? Is there a reason not to use them?

Comment: If the output quality looks good, it's fine.